# website can't refresh if i insert big cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to save a list in cookies that is quite big. I create various cookies each no more than the 4k limit and no more than 20 cookies are created. I escpaped the strings previously and even tried to compress with LZW and escaping correctly.

I have tried creating smaller cookies and it works succesfuly if my cookie size is 3300bytes approx and it is only 1 cookie, but if i create another cookie to store the rest of the information even if it is just a few bytes long when the browser refreshes it inmediatly fails responding it coudn't contact the server, and all pages from that site become inaccesible, that happens until i delete all cookies.

I am using session cookies, will changing them another type of cookie could work?
The server is a tomcat server, don't know if it affects.

I have tried it in chrome and firefox 2.0, and but have a similar hard limit. I thought firefox and chrome had a bigger limit than that.

Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

4k limit refers to ALL cookies in domain - not single one - also name of cookie is included into that limit

that is, the size of all data in cookies should not exceed 4093 bytes.

good place to test it http://browsercookielimits.x64.me/